# How to get the rest hours of the current week in PostegreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, datepart

i wanna find out how many hours are left in a current week from now in PostegreSQL

Comment: Please describe more.

Comment: i wanna predict how much sales i will get this week depending on the avg_hours_sales my formular looks like this : sales_now_this_week + (avg_sales_per_hour * rest_hours_this_week)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
WITH t(i) AS
     (SELECT age(
                date_trunc('week', current_timestamp)
                   + '1 week'::interval,
                current_timestamp
             )
     )
SELECT extract('days' FROM i) * 24
     + extract('hours' FROM i)
FROM t;
```